# C++ std:cout won't print, despite me using std::endl to enter newline and flush

Tags: c++, output, stdout

I'm new to C++ (and mainly programming in general).

I'm trying to write a basic program to output the Taylor expansion of x = 1.5 from n = 1 to n = 100. My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

        double x = 1.5;
        double expx = 1;
        double summand = 1;
        
        for (int n=1; n <100; ++n) {
                summand *= x/n;
                expx += summand;

        }
        return expx

        std::cout << "final expx from n = 1 to 100 is " << expx << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it, it runs without errors on terminal, but displays no output at all. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong as when I run other code I've written, similar to this, I don't have a problem.

Comment: You return from main before outputing to std::cout (note that your example code doesn't even compile)

Answer (score 0):

What you should have done is create an expx() function and output the result of that.

```
#include <iostream>

double expx()
{
    double x = 1.5;
    double expx = 1.0;
    double summand = 1.0;
        
    for (int n=1; n <100; ++n) 
    {
        summand *= x/n;
        expx += summand;
    }
    return expx;
}

int main() 
{
    double value = expx();
    std::cout << "final expx from n = 1 to 100 is " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you write after a return statement inside a function won't execute.
You need to switch the last two lines around, i.e:

```
std::cout << "final expx from n = 1 to 100 is " << expx << std::endl;
return expx
```